# Spark: Use JsonSchema to parse Json into DataFrame

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a file where each row is a stringified JSON.
I want to read it into a Spark DataFrame, along with schema validation.

#### The naive approach would be:

```
val schema: StructType = getSchemaFromSomewhere()
val df: DataFrame = spark.read
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .format("json")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("path/to/data.json")
```

However, this approach performs only some very basic schema validations.

- If a row is not parsable as json - it will be dropped.
- If a row contains a property with a value that can't be cast to the type defined by the `schema` - it will be dropped.
- BUT - this loading method ignores non-nullable fields (making them nullable in the resulting DF), and does not allow to fill in default values.

#### Approach 2 - use JsonSchema

In order to do that I can't use `spark.read.json()` anymore because I need the data to be in `JsonNode` format.
So instead I read it as a text file and parse it using the JsonSchema library:

```
def getJsonSchemaFactory: JsonSchemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault

def stringToJsonSchema(str: String): Try[JsonSchema] = {
  stringToJson(str).map(getJsonSchemaFactory.getJsonSchema(_))
}

def stringToJson(str: String): Try[JsonNode] = {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper
  Try({
    val json = mapper.readTree(str)
    json
  })
}

def validateJson(data: JsonNode): Boolean = {
  jsonSchema.exists(jsonSchema => {
    val report = jsonSchema.validateUnchecked(data, true)
    report.isSuccess
  })
}

lazy val jsonSchema: Option[JsonSchema] = stringToJsonSchema(schemaSource).toOption
val schema: StructType = getSchemaFromSomewhere()
val df = spark.read
  .textFile("path/to/data.json")
  .filter(str => {
    stringToJson(str)
      .map(validateJson)
      .getOrElse(false)
  })
  .select(from_json($"value", schema) as "jsonized")
  .select("jsonized.*")
```

The problem now is that I am parsing each `string` line into json twice - once inside the `filter`, and another time in the `select(from_json ...)`.

#### What I am looking for

Some way to read JSON data from a file to a DataFrame while also applying a JsonSchema validation on all the data - invalid data should be dropped (and maybe also logged somewhere).

- Is there a way to convert `Dataset[JsonNode]` to a `DataFrame` without parsing it more than once?
- Is there a way to convert a DF `Row` into `JsonNode` object? That way I could flip the order - first read the DF using `spark.read.json()` and then filter the DF by converting each `Row` to `JsonNode` and applying the `JsonSchema`.
- Is there some other way that I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to convert Dataset[JsonNode] to a DataFrame without parsing it more than once?

In most cases, the overhead of parsing twice is probably neglected compared to the total CPU usage of the job.

If that's not your case, you can implement you own `TableProvider` in `DataSourceV2`. This can be a decent long term solution if the parsing requirements might change or evolve over time.